# Photo Gallery in ruby on rails website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to make some simple image gallery for portfolio, maybe somebody can give some advise. I'm loogking for something like modal in Bootstap.

I have something like this for the moment

```
<article class="thumbnail">           
  <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal"><img src="/assets/project1.png" alt="Project1" /></a>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
       <h3 id="myModalLabel"><img src="/assets/project1.png" alt="Project1" /></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
       <a class="btn btn-info modal-prev"> Previous</a>
       <a class="btn btn-primary modal-next">Next <i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i></a>           
     </div>
   </div>
</article>
```

I'm thinking how to make my modal footer works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you are looking for a client-side implementation, i would recommend using Fancybox: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ This library is powerful, yet it is easy to use.

If you are looking for a scroller, try using FlexSlider: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider

**update**

Here is an example of how you can use Fancybox in rails app to display photos (taken from my working app):

In javascript folder there are two files: jquery.fancybox.pack.js and jquery.fancybox-buttons.js (because i also needed to use control buttons for my gallery). Also i have MouseWheel library, but this one is optional. In application.js (of course, you can have other libraries):

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require lib/jquery.mousewheel
//= require lib/jquery.fancybox.pack
//= require lib/jquery.fancybox-buttons

jQuery(function($) { // as soon as DOM is ready
$(".fancybox").fancybox({ // initialize fancybox on all pages where it is present
        helpers: {
            title: {type: 'inside'},
            buttons: {}
        }
    });
});
```

Also do not forget to download FancyBox styles and include it in your application.css.

In my view:

```
<% photos.each do |photo| %>
<%= link_to image_tag(photo.file.thumb('200x200#').url),
                photo.file.remote_url,
                class: 'fancybox', rel: 'group', title: photo.title, alt: 'Photo' %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: thank you. fancybox seams to be great solution,but to be honest(i know that is probably really simple),i'm not sure what i'm doin wrong.it seams to not working.i have at the begging all the scripts and then something like 

<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="/assets/images/project2.jpg"><img src="/assets/project2.jpg" alt="" /></a> is it the correct direction?

Comment: I updated the answer. Also take a look at fancybox demos; check your console to see if there are any error messages. If that helps, you can accept this answer. Otherwise i will try to put more example code.

Comment: thank you for you're time,but I'm still lost in this,maybe some more example will help.

Comment: well.now i see that i get errors in the console.i will try to work it out.it should be as simple as that http://jsfiddle.net/Py2RA/,but i'm just a beginner,that's why probably it's not.

Comment: Which errors do you get? Maybe I can help on that. And yes, basically integrating FancyBox is easy. You can visit my project's page with FancyBox integrated: http://www.la-theatre.ru/albums/11/photos (please note, that i also use turbolinks and lazyload).

Comment: well.i get many errors,some of them is this one:Error in event handler for 'undefined': Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined,and also 404 for all scripts,which a have. your gallery is exactly what i would like to have.

Comment: You got this on production or development? Error 404 could be because scripts are placed on wrong directory...